# is there a way to escape a string in powershell like @"string" in C#

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to escape a complete string i powershell the same way the @"string" Works in C#
I am writing a script and in there I have several strings that looks like this:
D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;AU)(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;PU)

escaping one by one There's is a long way home

Comment: Why are you needing to use @ on that string, you are not using `\ ` inside it so there is no need to do it. Also, as a FYI the official name for a `@"string"` is a "verbatim string literal"

Comment: Why is this question has -1 vote. It's a valid question.

Answer (score 20):

To quote verbatim strings in Powershell, just use single quotes:

```
'D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;AU)(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;PU)'
```

see

```
Get-Help about_Quoting_Rules
```

or [Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847740.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: This helped me run `npm test -- -w --grep='"/some.*(this|that)/i"'` to get all tests with 'some' (typically in the suite name) and containing 'this' or 'that' (typically in the test name).  (the actual words have been changed).  Thanks a bunch.  OP should definitely mark this as accepted.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a verbatim string modifier in PowerShell since backslashes are literals (and quotes are escaped by doubling).

For a [multiline string](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ee692792.aspx), use

```
$x = @"
"
Curiouser 
and 
curiouser
!
"
"@
```

Answer (score 2):

The keyword I was missing was **verbatim**:
http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/01/22/c-verbatim-strings-vs-powershell-here-strings/
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692792.aspx