# Powershell: using -split "\s+" as opposed to .split "\s+"

Tags: regex, parsing, powershell-4.0

**Prelude**

I am trying to perform an operation which requires me to parse every individual word a particular file. The most straightforward way of doing this would be to load the text using the:

```
$content = Get-Content -Path .\<filename>
```

Then I will break every individual word into an individual line (this allows me to do a word count AND single word search very quickly). The problem is when I then use this line of code:

```
$content.split("\s+")
```

which should create a new line (split) on every (one or more) whitespace character. Unfortunately, my results look like this:

```
$content.split("\s+")
The SpeechSynthe
izer cla

provide
acce

 to the functionality of a 
peech 
ynthe
 i
  engine that i
  in
talled on the ho
t computer. In
talled 
peech 
ynthe
 i
 engine
```

But when I run

```
$content -split("\s+")
```

The results will come out correctly:

```
$content -split("\s+")
The
SpeechSynthesizer
class
provides
access
to
the
functionality
of
a
speech
synthesis
```

**My question**
Using powershell V.4 I am having trouble understanding what the difference between performing the operation.

$content.split("\s+")

and

```
$content -split("\s+")
```

is. And why they are outputting different results.

Is that functionality just broken?

Is there some other difference that I am not aware of at play here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Powershelladmin wiki](http://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/Powershell_split_operator):

> The `-split` operator takes a regular expression, and to split on an arbitrary amount of whitespace, you can use the regexp `"\s+"`.

And

> To split on a single, or multiple, characters, you can also use the `System.String` object method `Split()`.
>
> `PS C:\> 'a,b;c,d'.Split(',') -join ' | '`
>   `a | b;c | d`
>   `PS C:\> 'a,b;c,d'.Split(',;') -join ' | '`
>   `a | b | c | d`

So, you just passed the symbols you need to split against with `$content.split("\s+")`, not the regex to match whitespace.

In `$content -split("\s+")`, `\s+` is a regex pattern matching *1 or more whitespace symbols*.

Comment: So you're saying that the System.String method does not support regex, and therefore, "\s+" does not mean  *one or more whitespace* in the context of '$content.split("\s+")' Correct?

Comment: Note it is not just that I am saying, but your example speaks for itself: all `s` letters were split against. *Synthe**s**izer*, etc. Your `$content.split("\s+")` splits by `s` and `+` (I guess ``\`` is considered as a wrong escape symbol and is ignored). Try yourself.

Comment: Now that you point that out; I can see now that is exactly what it is splitting against! I also tested against ' $content.split(" ") ' and it works exactly as expected. Thank you sir!

Comment: I just came across [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29459813/is-there-a-way-to-escape-a-string-in-powershell-like-string-in-c-sharp), it says that all strings are verbatim string literals, so, `$content.split("\s+")` should also split by ``\``, too.

Comment: I just tested. Confirmed your above statement @stribizhev. the "\" character will also split the line.