# Raw Output in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a string:

```
$string = "`nHello`n"
```

And I want to output the raw string data `` "`nHello`n" ``. Not it formatted like below:

```
"

Hello

"
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: use a string literal (single quotes instead of double): ``'`nHello`n'``

Comment: Thank you. How would I go about doing this for an already existing string?

Comment: maybe.
$string = "`nHello`n"
$string -replace "`n",""

Comment: ``$string -replace '\n','`n'``

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should be more specific here. I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue and want to compare raw values. There is a way to do it in python, but I am unable to find a way to do it in powershell. Here's the way in python for reference. http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-print-a-raw-string-in-Python.php#:~:text=To%20create%20a%20raw%20string,the%20string%20exactly%20as%20entered.

Comment: $string = "`nHello`n"
$string -replace "`n","``n"

Comment: The concept of a raw string only applies to _string literal_ representations, not to actual string _values_; the equivalent of a Python `r'...'` string is just `'...'` in PowerShell. It's still unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You could just write **``n** to replace **`n** so, in your script, you could write:

```
$string = "``nblah``n"
Write-Output $string
```

Output:

```
`nblah`n
```

Or if you want a more `r"\nblah\n"` python approach [you could use single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29470905/14087854)

```
$string = '`nblah`n'
Write-Output $string
```

Output:

```
`nblah`n
```